# validating properties with unknown keys - analog of io.record in runtypes

Tags: node.js, typescript, runtypes

I need to validate such type of fields in objects:

```
  "field_to_validate": {
    "inner_field_name_1": [
        "some_value_1",
        "some_value_2"
    ],
    "inner_field_name_2": [
        "some_other_value"
    ],
  },
```

at the time of validation, I don’t know what the names of the fields like inner_field_name_1 will be. I only know that inside each of them there will be an array

in io-ts i can validate it through:

```
field_to_validate: io.record(io.string, io.array(io.string))
```

how can i make it using runtypes?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own little check.

```
function validate(input) {
  return Object.values(input).every(entry => Array.isArray(entry))
}
```

If you want to validate the content of the array even further you could put it in a sep. validation function.

```
function validateArray(entry) {
  if(!Array.isArray(entry)) {
    return false
  }
  return entry.every(value => typeof value === 'string')
}

function validateInput(input) {
  return Object.values(input).every(entry => Array.isArray(entry))
}
```

If you have static validation (eg you know the fields (for example inside the array) i highly recommend JSON schema validation such as AJV  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

## edit:

AJV has also some semi dynamic validation build in, have a look at the patternproperties option https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#patternproperties